# Unwanted regions in ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

I have created a 3D plot and a contour plot for the same (Wigner) function, but as you see the contour plot is not right. It has some "extra" regions in gray color (ovals). What is going wrong?
The 3D plot code is

```
Plot3D[2/((2 + 2/E^8) \[Pi]) (Exp[-2 (4 - 4 x + x^2 + y^2)] + 
Exp[-2 (4 + 4 x + x^2 + y^2)] + 
2 Exp[-2 (x^2 + y^2)] Cos[8 y]), {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
PlotRange -> Full, Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 180, 
FaceGrids -> {{0, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, 
FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[Blue, Dotted], Boxed -> False, 
BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(W\), \(c\)]\)(x,y)"}, 
LabelStyle ->   {Bold, Black, FontSize -> 16}]
```

The contour plot code is

```
ContourPlot[
2/((2 + 2/E^8) \[Pi]) (Exp[-2 (4 - 4 x + x^2 + y^2)] + 
Exp[-2 (4 + 4 x + x^2 + y^2)] + 
2 Exp[-2 (x^2 + y^2)] Cos[8 y]), {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
PlotPoints -> 180]
```

And here are the figures:
[image]
[image]

The real contour plot is taken from a textbook (Quantum Optics by Girish Agarwal, Cambridge U Press, 2013, [page 80](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=7KKw_XIYaioC&pg=PA80)):

[image]

To emphasize that it is not a problem for a special case, here I have added another code and figure. You can see the "ugly" ovals are definitely incorrect.

```
ContourPlot[
1/((2 + 2/E^16) \[Pi])
2 (E^(((2 + 2 I) - x - I y) ((-2 + 2 I) + x - I y)) + 
E^(((-2 - 2 I) - x - I y) ((2 - 2 I) + x - I y)) + 
E^((-x - I y) (x - I y)) Cos[4 Im[(2 - 2 I) (x + I y)]]), {x, -4, 
4}, {y, -4, 4}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Frame ->  True,
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], PlotPoints -> 180, 
PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image]

Adding `Contours -> Range[-0.35, 0.35, 0.1] + 0.03` to my code generated the following plot, which is better, but another problem happened: the colors in the legend are not as they should be. For example, we have the same color for `(-0.12,-0.02)` and for `(0.28,0.38)`

[image]

Comment: What if you add `PlotRange -> All` to `ContourPlot[]`?

Comment: "from a textbook" - which textbook? If you don't give a citation, that statement is not very useful.

Comment: Quantum Optics by Girish Agarwal, Cambridge U Press, 2013, page 80

Comment: PlotRange -> All did not work

Comment: Try `Contours -> Range[-0.55, 0.55, 0.1] + 0.025` with `PlotRange -> All`.

Comment: does the textbook tell you the values for the contour lines?

Comment: No, the textbook emphasizes on the qualitative behavior.

Comment: Yes, Contours -> Range[-0.55, 0.55, 0.1] + 0.025 worked! Can you explain it?

Comment: Site tip: use @username to make sure a user is notified of your response. -- Evaluate `Range[-0.55, 0.55, 0.1] + 0.025` to see the numbers produced.  `ContourPlot` will draw the level sets corresponding to these values of the function.  The offset from the zero contour by `+0.025` avoids the small oscillations that Rom38's answer shows.

Comment: @Michael E2. I have edited my question.

Comment: @Saeid - the original question was about the unexpected extra lines, and I think that was answered by JimB's answer.  The wrong color issue you are seeing looks like a bug to me, entirely separate from this question.  I will look to get a more minimal example that shows the problem.

Comment: Simple example of the color function bug: `ContourPlot[
   0.3 (Exp[-8 + 4 x - x^2 + 4 y - y^2]), {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
   Contours -> #, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic] & /@ {Range[-.01, 0.39, 0.1], Automatic}`

Answer (score 6):

It looks normal because if you try to draw the 1D dependence:

```
Plot[(2/((2 + 2/E^8) \[Pi]) (Exp[-2 (4 - 4 x + x^2 + y^2)] + 
      Exp[-2 (4 + 4 x + x^2 + y^2)] + 
      2 Exp[-2 (x^2 + y^2)] Cos[8 y])) /. x -> 0, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, All}, AxesLabel -> {Y, Z}, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Plot[(2/((2 + 2/E^8) \[Pi]) (Exp[-2 (4 - 4 x + x^2 + y^2)] + 
         Exp[-2 (4 + 4 x + x^2 + y^2)] + 
         2 Exp[-2 (x^2 + y^2)] Cos[8 y])) /. x -> 0, {y, 1.7, 2.5}, 
    Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {-0.0005, 0.0001}], 
   Scaled@{0.715, 0.75}]]
```

Then:

[image]

The inset shows the small oscillations of the `Z[y]` at `y>1.5`

Comment: I added the real contour plot from a textbook. It shows that something is wrong

Comment: It's likely that the textbook is wrong.  Those "extra" contours are contours of zero.  The interior of those contours are very slightly negative.  Try adding `Contours->{0}` to see that.  And write a note to the textbook author.

Comment: @JimB - it isn't necessarily that the textbook is wrong, just that they made a decision not to put a contour at 0. This is a reasonable choice with decaying oscillatory functions.  It's possible the authors list the contour values in the figure caption.

Comment: @JasonB.  No disagreement with your comment.  It is the color scheme plus the contour lines that makes things appear more extreme than they are.  I was also using the more binary choice of "right" and "wrong" implied by the OP.

Comment: @JasonB.  You should write-up your answer about not having a contour at zero.  Using `Contours -> {-0.4, -0.35, -0.3, -0.25, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0.05,  0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3}` (which avoids the zero contour) seems to reconcile the issue.

Comment: @JimB. Is there any systematic way to avoid that? I added another example and tried to remove some contours as you did, but the problem is still there.

Comment: @JimB, sorry I missed your comment.  I think your answer actually is complete and gives the reason for the unexpected line.

Comment: @Saeid there is a simple way - just exclude the near-zero contours from the list of drawn. You can do it by manual declaration of the needed heights to draw (using `Contour->{z1, z2, z3,...}`) as said JimB.